# Long type 64bit linux

Tags: c, linux, bit-manipulation

Very simple questions guys, but maybe I'm just forgetting something.
In 64bit linux, a long is 8bytes correct?
If that's the case, and I want to set the 64th bit, I can do the following:

```
unsigned long num = 1<<63;
```

Whenever I compile this, however, it gives me an error saying that I'm left shifting by more than the width.
Also, if I wanted to take the first 32bits of a long type (without sign extension), can I do:

```
num = num&0xFFFFFFFF;
```

or what about:

```
num = (int)(num);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try: `unsigned long num = 1UL << 63;`

Comment: @Mysticial Why not post that as an answer along with the integer promotion stuff ?

Comment: Depends on which compiler is used.  Many legacy compilers would default to 32-bit longs, even if running on a 64 bit machine.  Confirm that `sizeof num` is 8 before trying anything more.

Comment: @cnicutar After you answer the same questions many times over and over again, it starts to get old. So I can't get myself to do more than a 1 line answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [warning: left shift count >= width of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201301/warning-left-shift-count-width-of-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In 64bit linux, a long is 8bytes correct?

Need not be. Depends on the compiler than on the underlying OS. Check this for a nice discussion.
[What decides the sizeof an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689049/what-decides-the-sizeof-an-integer)

> Whenever I compile this, however, it gives me an error saying that I'm
>   left shifting by more than the width

Everyone have already answered this. Use `1UL`

> Also, if I wanted to take the first 32bits of a **long** type (without
>   sign extension), can I do:

```
num = num&0xFFFFFFFF;
or what about:

num = (int)(num);
```

`num = num&0xFFFFFFFF`. This will give you the lower 32-bits. But note that if `long` is just 4 bytes on your system then you are getting the *entire number*. Coming to the sign extension part, if you've used a `long` and not `unsigned long` then you cannot do away with the sign extended bits. For example, `-1` is represented as all ones, right from the 0th bit. How will you avoid these ones by masking?

`num = (int)(num)` will give you the lower 32-bits but compiler might through a Overflow Exception warning if `num` does not fit into an `int`

Comment: Agree that C doesn't impose `long` to be 64bits on 64bits machine. However linux implicitely imposes that. Just take a look at all the pointers passed through `unsigned long` and memory offsets passed through `signed long` (e.g. syscalls). Thus, as long as linux source code doesn't drastically change, I would answer **yes** to the question : "In 64bit linux, a `long` is 8bytes, correct ?"

Answer (score 4):

Actually, if you want some precise length (in bits) for your integers, assuming a *C99* conforming compiler, `#include <stdint.h>` and use types like `int64_t`, `int32_t`  etc. A handy type is `intptr_t`, an integer type with the same number of bits as `void*` pointer (so you can call it a machine "word")

Comment: A C99 conforming compiler does not need to provide fixed-width types, e.g. `int64_t`. Only twos-complement implementations that provide 8-, 16-, 32- and 64-bit integer types with no padding bits are *required* to provide fixed-width integer typedefs in `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 1):

For portability you could use:

limits.h

```
#define LNG_BIT   (sizeof(long) * CHAR_BIT)

unsigned long num = 1UL << (LNG_BIT - 1);
```

---

To get "*low int*", something like?:

```
#define INT_BIT   (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)

if (LNG_BIT > INT_BIT)
    return num & (~0UL >> INT_BIT);
else
    return num;
```

or

```
    num &= ~(~0U << INT_BIT);
```

Or, use mask, etc. Depends in large on why, for what, etc. you want the int bits.

Also notice the options given by compilers; I.e. if you are using gcc:

- [i386 and x86-64 Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html)
- [Submodel-Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Submodel-Options.html#Submodel-Options)

<sup>-m32

-m64

-mx32</sup>

         <sub>Generate code for a 32-bit or 64-bit environment.

         * The -m32 option sets int, long, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code that runs on any i386 system.

         * The -m64 option sets int to 32 bits and long and pointer types to 64 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture. For Darwin only the -m64 option also turns off the -fno-pic and -mdynamic-no-pic options.

         * The -mx32 option sets int, long, and pointer types to 32 bits, and generates code for the x86-64 architecture.</sub>

There is also `-maddress-mode=long` etc.

<sup>-maddress-mode=long</sup>
         <sub>Generate code for long address mode. This is only supported for 64-bit and x32 environments. It is the default address mode for 64-bit environments.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR code like this was the source of a major bug in reiserfs a few years ago:

```
unsigned long num = 1<<63;
```

If you speak of x86_64, yes, a long is 64 bit and on most other 64 bit linux plytforms too. The problem is that both the `1` and the `63` in your code are simple `int`, and so the result is undefined. Better use

```
 unsigned long num = 1UL<<63;
```

or

```
 unsigned long num = (unsigned long)1<<63;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with the first question is that the compiler is treating '1' as an integer, not as a long integer.  It doesn't figure it out until after the assignment.

You can fix it by doing:

```
unsigned long num = (unsigned long)1<<63;
```

Comment: Do you happen to know the answer to the second part of my question. About obtaining the non-sign-extended first 32 bits? Would I do something similar to num = num&(unsigned long)(0xFFFFFFFF)?

Comment: @de1337ed I've answered the second part of your Qn. Check out