# Why does C++'s reinterpret_cast not work when Rust's std::mem::transmute does work?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

The following Rust code:

```rs
use std::mem;
fn main() {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    #[repr(C)]
    struct Test {
        y: f32,
        x: u32,
    }
    let a = Test { x: 1, y: 1.2 };
    let y = unsafe { mem::transmute::<Test, u64>(a) };
    let b = unsafe { mem::transmute::<u64, Test>(y) };
    println!("{y} {} {}", b.x, b.y);
}
```

Works fine: `5361998234 1 1.2`

The equivalent (in my opinion) C++ code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    unsigned int x;
    float y;
};

int main() {
    Test a = Test{1, 1.2};
    long y = *reinterpret_cast<long *>(&a);
    Test t = *reinterpret_cast<Test *>(&y);
    std::cout << y << " " << t.x << " " << t.y << std::endl;
}
```

does not: `1 1 1.4013e-45`

I've tried all of the following different ways of doing the `reinterpret_cast`

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    unsigned int x;
    float y;
};

int main() {
    Test *a = new Test{1, 1.2};
    long y = *reinterpret_cast<long *>(&a);
    Test t = *reinterpret_cast<Test *>(&y);
    std::cout << y << " " << t.x << " " << t.y << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    unsigned int x;
    float y;
};

int main() {
    Test *a = new Test{1, 1.2};
    long y = *reinterpret_cast<long *>(a);
    Test t = *reinterpret_cast<Test *>(&y);
    std::cout << y << t.x << " " << t.y << std::endl;
}
```

None of these seem to work, generating different outputs for each.
What am I doing wrong? What would be a correct equivalent of the Rust program?

Note: This is for purely recreational purposes, there is no reason for me to do this, I just want to.

Comment: hm, not equivalent: your rust first element is a float32, your C++ x the first element is an `unsigned int` (so probably, an int32)

Comment: *The equivalent (in my opinion) C++ code* — you have different order of struct fields and types of variables, and you transmute/reinterpret to a different type. Why did you make these changes and why do you feel they are equivalent? Why is the printed order different?

Comment: A `long` is neither required nor guaranteed to be 64 bit. That's why there's types such as `uintptr_t` for when you really need to store an address in an integer

Comment: Warning is quite clear: https://godbolt.org/z/1adr6Mv4K and seems to "work".

Comment: Is `long` large enough to hold a pointer on your platform? The fact that printing `y` outputs `1` suggests that it isn't

Comment: Also for which platform you are compiling? Note that `long` can have different size depending on platform. https://godbolt.org/z/Td3qhcx1z

Comment: @Shepmaster  Just stuff left over from when i was messing around, the following rust works just as fine though, https://godbolt.org/z/3cMdP1Gbh

Comment: `long y = *reinterpret_cast<long *>(a);` is undefined Behaviour  in C++ as `long` and `Test` are not related types.  So is `Test t = *reinterpret_cast<Test *>(&y);` for the same reason.  Undefined Behaviour _"...Renders the entire program meaningless...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub  `std::memcpy` is probably the only option.

Comment: @MarekR the following doesn't work https://godbolt.org/z/d31srT7jr , why?

Comment: @yaxleypeaks typo: https://godbolt.org/z/ze5oYoPzG

Comment: @RichardCritten: `Test` and `unsigned int` aren't "related" in the usual sense the word is used (inheritance), yet casting a pointer-to-structure as pointer-to-first-member is allowed as long as the structure is standard-layout.  That doesn't help here, but it shows that "related types" is not the correct criteria.

Comment: @yaxleypeaks: That may appear to work, but it's still *wrong*.

Comment: @yaxleypeaks please note that this code opens word of [nasal demons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @BenVoigt yes i know, the program is undefined behaviour. I know that very well. I just wanted to have some fun. I realize I am to never use it in production

Comment: How big is `long` on your system? 4 bytes, by chance?

Comment: `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int)` and almost always they are equal. The only cases I know when it's larger are systems with `sizeof(int)` equal to 2.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `long` is 64-bit on 64-bit Linux and macos: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: @AlanBirtles for 10 years I'm working on a 64bit linux distro and that's not the case on that one, at least. I saw that being a brief case for 2.6 kernel. `long long` takes 64bit mantle.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I could be wrong, I avoid using `long` on any platform for this reason but everything I've read says 64-bit Linux is usually 64-bit longs, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040123/long-type-64bit-linux https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch11.pdf

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `reinterpret_cast` doesn't relax [strict aliasing rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), so it cannot be used for punning arbitrary types.  The only transmutation allowed universally is to inspect an object as a sequence of narrow character (`char` or `signed char` or `unsigned char` and/or `std::byte`).

You should instead use `std::memcpy` as Richard Critten suggested in a comment.  In most cases the compiler will generate the same efficient machine code, but also handle aliasing assumptions correctly.

Comment: ... or `std::bit_cast`?

Comment: @MatG: That seems to just be a wrapper around `std::memcpy`, so it's fine to use.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if it this helps, but I wrote what seems to be a rough equivalent of Rust's `std::mem::transmute` using a union, based on this reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/1139u3v/equivalent_of_rusts_memforget_for_avoiding/j8qdy1a/

```cpp
template <class To, class From>
std::enable_if_t<sizeof(To) == sizeof(From) && alignof(To) == alignof(From), To>
transmute(From from) {
    union Union {
        From from;
        To to;

        ~Union() {}
    };

    Union un = {};
    un.from = std::move(from);
    return std::move(un.to);
}
```