# Left shifting with a unit64_t - Gives warning

Tags: c++

I am trying to do the following. However I am not sure where I might be going wrong

```
uint64_t x = (1 << 46); 
std::cout << x;
```

I get the

> -warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]

I get the output 0. I was expecting something a decimal output of a binary like this

```
1 0000........00 (46 0s)
```

My question is why am I getting this warning ? isnt uint64_t 64 bit ? also why am I getting the output 0 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning: left shift count >= width of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201301/warning-left-shift-count-width-of-type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are not shifting a 64-bit constant: `1` is a constant of type `int`, which is less than 64 bits on your platform (probably 32 bits; it is implementation-defined).

You can fix this by using `UINT64_C` macro around the constant:

```
uint64_t x = (UINT64_C(1) << 46);
```

Comment: Is macro `UINT64_C` part of standard C/C++?

Comment: @KaiserKatze Yes, it's part of [`<cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint)

Comment: Or you could decorate the constant with a type suffix: 1ull.

Answer (score 1):

1 is a 32-bit constant. The compiler (correctly) computes the constant expression as 0 --- the 1 shifted beyound the size of an int32. If the arguments to << were variables, an x86 cpu would return (1 << 14), i.e. 1 << (46 % 32).
Try "1ULL << 46".

Comment: Shifting wider than the width of the type is undefined behaviour (not 0)

Comment: Why would using a variable make this into a shift by 14 on an x86 CPU?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen • undefined behavior can do unexpected things.  In this case, x86 does modulo 32 on the shift.