# left shifting unsigned int to 32 bits, generates warning

Tags: c, bit-shift

Why does left shifting `unsigned int` 32 times generates below warning?

```
pthr.c: In function ‘main’:
pthr.c:4: warning: left shift count >= width of type
```

Even though `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4 bytes on my system.

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(void) 
{ 
    unsigned int mask = 1u << 32; 
    printf("sizeof(unsigned int) = %u\n", sizeof(unsigned int)); 
    return 0;  
}
```

**gcc --version**

```
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: It is undefined behavior, Use at most 31 instead of 32.

Comment: [warning: left shift count >= width of type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4201301/5291015)